Who should the moderators be?
As per the 7 essential questions, we should start to suggest temporary moderators for the site.
There will be a more formal election process later on, but I think that the site could really use some temporary moderators at this point to regulate some of the soft questions, etc.  Moderators have access to tools to merge questions, close/lock questions, remove spam users, etc.
Please nominate one person per answer, including links to their main page and meta page (meta contribution is also really important).  The nominee should feel free to add more details, including whether they are willing to do the job.
Edit:
Just to add, Jeff Atwood posted a great "Theory of Moderation" post in the past, which sums up their view of what makes a good moderator.  Please feel free to provide other suggestions for what makes a good moderator in the comments (sorry...I would make this CW, but I can't after the fact and am not a moderator yet...will ask one of the StackExchange folks to do it for me).

I assume you'll be a moderator too, right? I wouldn't have it any other way.

@chrisaycock Would be quite happy to; feel free to nominate me.  :)

Shane
meta
Shane proposed this site and has so far racked-up the highest reputation. He and Dirk are the only gold tag-badge holders of R on Stack Overflow.

Thanks Chris; I will accept the nomination.  I work in the Eastern time zone (NY), so I can cover moderator activities for most of those hours.

My view of the site: I believe that it should be "expert friendly" primarily, but that everyone should be treated with respect and given the benefit of the doubt.  This is a community driven process: a moderator should be mostly invisible, and try to help build the community through consensus.  As an example, I have been promoting positive voting (http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10/vote-early-vote-often) and accepted as scope issue that I disagreed with (http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36/is-sports-betting-on-topic).  Mostly: I'm excited about it!

Dirk Eddelbuettel
meta
Dirk is a very active contributor on other StackExchange sites, especially on StackOverflow where he is on page 5 of users and the highest rated R contributor.  He also contributes significantly to the R community, including finance packages like RQuantlib.

chrisaycock
meta
Beyond working in finance and providing good answers, Chris has been one of the most active users on the site, including on meta and in chat.  

richardh
meta
Richard is a finance Ph.D. student and has provided great contributions to the site thus far.

Brian B
meta
Brian has been the most active user in the past week with some excellent answers, and has contributed on meta.

Happy to be nominated, my contribution rate will be stochastic as my free time comes in waves (I am chief scientist at a large hedge fund and adjunct faculty at a local university).

gappy
meta
gappy has been increasingly one of the top contributors and is a professional in the field.
